# Get text() in selenium not returning the text

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I have a question regarding xpath. I try to get the text using the code shown in the screenshot.

I want to get the text from this xpath (Yes).

In console when I write:

```
//*[@id='info_is_network']/label[contains(@class , "ant-radio-button-wrapper ant-radio-button-wrapper-checked ant-radio-button-wrapper-disabled" )]/span/text(`)
```

It is OK and finds the element.

However in code when I do:

```
WebElement element = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='info_is_network']/label[contains(@class , \"ant-radio-button-wrapper ant-radio-button-wrapper-checked ant-radio-button-wrapper-disabled\" )]/span"));
String res = element.getText();
String res2 = element.getAttribute("value");
```

I get null or nothing in both attempts.

What can be the reason? No error in logs. Just copy from the dev tools to the intelij.

[image]

The Screen PIC (Buttons Not clickable, view only )

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given xpath is finding the first span element.That explains why you are getting null. you have to get the following sibiling to get the correct text.try this xpath,

```
   WebElement element = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='info_is_network']/label[contains(@class , \"ant-radio-button-wrapper ant-radio-button-wrapper-checked ant-radio-button-wrapper-disabled\" )]/span/following-sibling:span"));
   String res = element.getText();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with below code.

```
element.getAttribute("textContent"));
```

Answer (score 0):

After Investigation
this also do the work:

```
driver2.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='info_is_network']/label[contains(@class , \"ant-radio-button-wrapper ant-radio-button-wrapper-checked ant-radio-button-wrapper-disabled\" )]/span[text()]
```